# Powershell search and append text in a string by looking for specific word located only at the end of a line

Tags: string, powershell, search, replace, append

I have a bunch of PNACH files I have been working on for a collection of PS2 games to run on PCSX2. Upon completion, I found that it is difficult to tell where blocks of "codes" are because they all just have "//whatever codes" as a comment before a bunch of relevant cheats below them. Example:

//Ammo Codes

//Activate Cheat Codes

//Amelia Codes

Etc...

I am trying to find all lines in all PNACH files in a directory ending with the word "codes" (non case sensitive), and replace them with this:

//<<<<<<<< Ammo Codes >>>>>>>>

//<<<<<<<< Activate Cheat Codes >>>>>>>>

//<<<<<<<< Amelia Codes >>>>>>>>

Etc...

I already figured out how to use this script earlier to fix another issue, so I would like to use something similar for the task at hand:

```
$DirPath = "E:\PC Emulators\PCSX2\cheats"
get-childitem $DirPath -recurse -include *.pnach |
ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content $_).replace("patch=1","//patch=1") |
    Set-Content $_
}
```

I have been trying to research how to do what I want, but it's just too confusing. The codes below are what I dug up, but I'm not sure how to use either of those to achieve what I want...

Multiline: -match '^*codes$'
-match '(.+codes )(.+)'

I am pretty sure that the solution is simple, but I can't figure it out on my own. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The following uses regular expressions and capture groups to surround the “… Codes” text with arrows…

```
$txt = @(
    "aaa",
    "//Ammo Codes",
    "bbb"
)

$txt | foreach-object {
    $_ -replace "^//(.* Codes)`$", "//<<<<< `$1 >>>>>"
}
```

Notes:

- `^` matches the start of a string
- `( … )` creates an anonymous capture group that can be referenced in the replacement string
- `$` matches the end of a string
- `$1` in the second string is a reference to the text captured by the first capture group - when the replace is evaluated this will insert the value of the capture group

The result is that any lines starting with `//` and ending with `Codes` will have the `//` discarded and the remaining text surrounded by angle brackets, and the result of that is then prefixed with new `//`.

In the code above, the output is:

```
aaa
//<<<<< Ammo Codes >>>>>
bbb
```

You can pipe `Get-Content` into the above and pipe the output into `Set-Content` to perform the file IO…

```
Get-Content … `
    | ForEach-Object {
        $_ -replace "^//(.* Codes)`$", "//<<<<< `$1 >>>>>"
    } `
    | Set-Content …
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following which doesn't use a lot of memory because the entire file is not in memory at one time :

```
$inputFilename = 'c:\temp\test.txt'
$outputFilename = 'c:\temp\test1.txt'

$reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($inputFilename)
$writer = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($outputFilename)
while(($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null)
{
   if($line.EndsWith('Codes'))
   {
      $code = $line.Substring(2)
      $line = [string]::Format('//<<<<<<<< {0} >>>>>>>>', $code)
   }
   $writer.WriteLine($line)
}
$reader.Close()
$Writer.Flush()
$Writer.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your help. Mclayton had the most simple solution for what I needed and was most relevant to my original request. This is what I came up with that worked. Though, for some reason, I had to use `-ireplace` to get powershell to ignore case sensitivity. I thought is was insensitive by default, but it's using case on my machine for some reason:

```
$DirPath = "E:\PC Emulators\PCSX2\cheats"

$txt = @()

get-childitem $DirPath -recurse -include *.pnach |

    ForEach-Object {
        (Get-Content $_)-ireplace("^//(.+codes$)","//<<<<<<<< `$1 >>>>>>>>") |
        Set-Content $_
}
```

The key was being able to capture the string into a variable for each instance and then pass it into the replace function. I am assuming the back-tick symbol is to allow the `$` character to reference the stored string variable without being interpreted literally, although I am not sure. Being able to discard the two initial "//" was also another issue I did not think of that was addressed before it could bite me in the butt.

Jdweng. Thanks for your time. I am sure it took you a little while to write that up. It looks more complicated than Mclayton's answer, and it's on a whole different level for me. I am curious though, so I will be doing some research on the code you have provided to figure out exactly what is going on there. :)  Thanks again both of you for helping me solve this problem.

Comment: Backtick is the powershell string escape character in *double-quoted* strings - in my answer, ```"<<<<< $1 >>>>>"``` (without the backtick) would have substitute d```$1``` with the value of the variable ```$1``` from the main powershell script (which is presumably undefined in your script) so would be equivalent to ```"//<<<<<  >>>>>"```. The backtick before the ```$``` tells powershell to use a literal ```$``` in the string instead of interpolating it - I could have used *single-quote* insteads - e.g. ```'//<<<<< $1 >>>>>'``` but I'm a creature of habit and prefer double-quotes everywhere :-)

Comment: In short, I want the ```-replace``` operator to receive the literal string ```//<<<<<<<< $1 >>>>>>>>``` as a parameter, but in order to do that I have to remember that the PowerShell parser will process my source code first, so I have feed a backtick to the parser to tell it to leave my ```$``` alone :-) - i.e. ```"//<<<<<<<< `$1 >>>>>>>>"``` in my source code gets parsed into ```//<<<<<<<< $1 >>>>>>>>``` as an in-memory string that gets given to ```-replace```

Comment: Thanks for that very detailed description. I learned a lot from it. This solution you helped me with took a task that would have taken me many hours and processed all of the files in less than 3 seconds. You are the man!